# Mul + div using only add/sub ?

Tags: algorithms, computer-algebra

In an algorithm book once the first example was how to compute a multiplication in a loop (only that, so I just remembered, and wanted to do it programmatically but with all operations)

Multiplication was simple, say 10 * 4:

base = 0, x = 10, y = 4:

```
While y != 0:
base + x = 10, y--
base + x = 20, y--
base + x = 30, y--
base + x = 40, y-- (y is now 0)

Result of base: 40 (correct)
```

As the opposite of taking away is giving, I assumed the same was for division and multiplication (doubling, halving), but: `"base - x.."` clearly does not give anything useful in an iteration..

Is this impossible? Am I looking at an algorithm to divide completely the wrong way (not like my mult)?

Comment: Take away x until you would go below zero.  The number of times you took x away is the quotient.  The number left is the remainder.  Is this what you are looking for?  Or do you want a decimal expansion of the fraction you get?  By the way, you cannot multiply fractions using your algorithm - what is 1/2 times 1/3?  Add 1/3 to itself repeatedly 1/2 a time? A computer would no take that instruction.

Comment: Have you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithms ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Division is repeated subtraction. Take 11 \div 3 as an example.

11 - 3 = 8.
Increment the quotient by 1.
Since 8 > 3, keep going.

8 - 3 = 5.
Increment the quotient by 1.
Since 5 > 3, keep going.

5 - 3 = 2.
Increment the quotient by 1.
Since 2 < 3, set the remainder to 2 and terminate.

I'll leave it to you to figure out the code.